# Showing integrability

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Define the function $f\colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$$f(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       1 & x = \frac{1}{n}, \, n \in \mathbb{Z}\\
       0  & \text{otherwise}
     \end{cases}
$$

The question asks to show that $f$ is integrable and that $\int_0^1f(x) \, dx = 0$. My approach is to try to kill two birds with one stone and attempt to show that the upper-integral is equal to the lower-integral which equals $0$.

However I run into the following problem. It is not hard to show that the lower-integral is $0$ since for any subinterval $I \subset [0,1]$ there is always an irrational number $x \in I \Rightarrow f(x) = 0$. The problem is when I try to show the upper-integral is equal to $0$. Since some subintervals will contain $x = \frac{1}{n}$, $\,\,f(x) = 1$ in these subintervals. This means $\sup \{f(x) \mid x \in I\} = 1$ for some subintervals $I$. Thus, the upper-integral is not identically $0$. Is there a different way of showing the integrability of $f$? We also cannot use the theorem that states $f\colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ if it is bounded and piecewise continuous on $[a,b]$, since $f$ is clearly discontinuous for an infinite number of points in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Instead of \;|\; you can use \mid (and I changed it, along with some other things included "cases").  \mid yields different spacings in different contexts, behaving about like \;|\; if there's something on each side of it, and more like | without spacing if there's something on only one side. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to show the upper integral is equal to zero, then you are doing something that might be more difficult than the problem is asking. Let us try the "$\epsilon$" trick.

let $\epsilon$ be given, define 
$$g = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \chi_{(\frac{1}{n}- \frac{\epsilon}{2^n},\frac{1}{n}+ \frac{\epsilon}{2^n})}$$
Observe that $f\leq g$, and
$$\int f\;d\mu\leq \int g\;d\mu = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mu(\frac{1}{n}- \frac{\epsilon}{2^n},\frac{1}{n}+ \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} 2 \frac{\epsilon}{2^n} = 2\epsilon.$$
Since we can make $2\epsilon$ arbitrarily small, $\int f\; d\mu$ must be zero.

Answer (score 0):

For all $\varepsilon >0$, let $N$ be an integer larger than $\varepsilon^{-1}$.
Let

$$E_\varepsilon = [0, \varepsilon ] \cup \bigcup_{k=1}^N \left[ \frac{1}{k} - 2^{-k}\varepsilon ,  \frac{1}{k} \right]$$ this is a finite union of intervals.

Note that the measure of $E_\varepsilon$ is
$$\int_{E_\varepsilon} dx \leq \varepsilon + \sum_{k=1}^N 2^{-k}\varepsilon \leq \varepsilon \left( 1+ \sum_{k=1}^N 2^{-k} \right) \leq \varepsilon \left( 1+ \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} 2^{-k} \right) = 2 \varepsilon$$

Finally, define
$$\phi_{\varepsilon}(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       1 &\mbox{ if } x \in E_\varepsilon \\
       0  & \text{otherwise}
     \end{array}
   \right.$$
It is easy to see that $0 \leq f \leq \phi_{\varepsilon}$. So
$$\inf \{\mbox{upper sums}\} \leq \inf_{\varepsilon >0} \int_0^1 \phi_{\varepsilon}(x) dx \leq \inf_{\varepsilon >0} 2 \varepsilon =0$$

Comment: I believe your proof uses material that is a bit advanced for me. Is there a way to approach this question using just elementary facts about integration (material covered in an undergraduate course)?

Comment: I think this is the simplest way to show integrability of such a function. I invite you not to be frightened about my notation... I just showed that you can find arbitrarily small upper sums, and the idea is indeed very simple.

Comment: In that case, could you explain why my work does not show that $f$ is not integrable? That is, what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: I think the problem is when you say "so the upper integral is not identically 0". This makes no sense to me, because the upper integral is not a function: it is an $\inf$. What you have to show is that this $\inf$ is $\leq 0$. Now you are saying : "how can we do this? the function is equal to 1 in some points". My answer: isolate these points inside a finite union of intervals whose measure is small. Then outside these intervals the function is 0, so the upper integral cannot be too large.

Comment: Ok, that explanation makes a lot of sense. Thanks.